# Is IQueryable ToList() preferred to .Count() when results are probable?

Tags: c#, .net

This is a question about performance more than anything. Here follows a pattern I see a lot in both my own code and the code of my colleagues

```
var items = GetItems();
```

The variable `items` now contains an `IQueryable` that will return one, multiple or no rows from the database.

and then:

```
if (items.Any()) {
    //do something, but only if there are items
    foreach (var item in items) {
      ...
    }
    //do something else, but only if there are items
}
```

So we would execute two actions and a loop in case there are items. Assuming that there will **usually** be items returned, wouldn't it make more sense to edit the above code to:

```
var items = GetItems().ToList();
```

so my `Any()` (or sometimes even `.Count() > 0`)

What do you think about this? Assume that the GetItems() returns a complicated query which isn't slow per se, but still quite complicated.

Comment: Can it return so many results that you don't want to have them all in memory?

Answer (score 2):

If performance is crucial and you don't want to load all into memory at once, you could use this approach which doesn't need to execute the query multiple times:

```
bool anyItems = false; bool firstItem = true;
foreach (var item in items) 
{
    anyItems = true;
    if(firstItem)
    {
       //do something, but only if there are items and only once
        firstItem = false;
    }
    // do something with this item
}
if(anyItems)
{
    //do something else, but only if there are items
}
```

If you don't expect many items you can use `ToList`, then you don't need to care about multiple `Any` or `Count` calls and you can even access items at a given index(f.e. in a for-loop).

So the `ToList` costs memory but

- gives you an unconnected snapshpot of your items
- makes your code easier to read
- enables to use the indexer or a for-loop

Using the `IQueryable` saves memory but

- gives you always the current state(`items.Any` could yield a different result later)
- code is less readable as you can see above
- is like a stream so you can't use a for-loop or an indexer

Comment: The OP needs code to be executed before the iterations too, but only if there are items. With your answer, that can be done by adding an `if (!anyItems) { ... }` at the top of the loop body. The variable name becomes a bit misleading in that case though.

Comment: Using foreach still executes whole query like ToList, so you are not saving any memory or time. It does NOT retrieve items from db one by one. The same for the other solution from @Evk

Comment: @LukaszCokot Yes, but it will depend on the IQueryable implementation and maybe there is some internal paging implemented. Dealing with EF I think it is like you wrote and the query is executed and the complete resultset is loaded into memory.

Comment: @LukaszCokot: i didn't know. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055948/284240) suggests that it's possible to control the behaviour of Linq-To-Entities

Comment: @TimSchmelter You have to look at the resultset which has the data from the query and the mapped entities. Without detaching/NoTracking the data is loaded twice in memory (resultset + instance tracked by context)

Comment: @LukaszCokot do you have some link confirming that in EF enumeration immediately loads all items into memory?

Comment: @Evk sorry I don't have such link, but You can easily confirm that by using IQuerable in foreach loop and use profiler to see the query and when You iterate over collection there won't be any other queries to db. It means that everything was in memory already.

Comment: @LukaszCokot But that's different. Of course it will execute query to get all items, but it will read them from DataReader one by one.

Comment: @Evk Question is about performance, so any() or count() in most cases will be much faster than doing foreach on resultset, most expensive part is query and reading into memory, both of those steps have beedn already done by foreach. You can try run Any() and ToList() in parallel to and if any() finish faster you don't have for example to wait for tolist but in this case you gain speed but you still run two queries to db.

Comment: @LukaszCokot After a simple test I can state for EF-SQL-Server that the resultset itself is not loaded completely into memory (of the process).

Answer (score 1):

You better just do:

```
bool anyItems = false;
foreach (var item in items) {
    anyItems = true;
    // do stuff       
}
```

That way you execute query just once and not pull all items into memory at once. If you don't really need to know if there were items or not - you can remove `anyItems` flag.

If you need to do something before processing items - do that on the first iteration of the loop, before processing first item:

```
bool firstItem = true;
foreach (var item in items) {
    if (firstItem) {
        // do something, but only if there are items
        firstItem = false;
    }
    // handle item          
}
```

If this will provide much benefits or not depends on your situation. If you don't expect thousands of items - you can just use `ToList`. If you expect a lot of those queries to return 0 items - you might prefer doing `Any` queries, but only if they are much faster (you should measure that yourself). If you don't expect majority of queries to return 0 items  - it's better to always use this approach (or `ToList`) to save one database query.

Comment: I think it is not that simple. In your case you always execute the query which return GetItems query which might be big and slow. And if you just want to know if there is any record Any() or you want to know number of rows in query Count() you should use those methods because it will execute different query which probably will be faster. So it depends what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @LukaszCokot but if there are items you will execute 2 queries. Without additional information (for example without knowledge that 95% of time there will be no items) you better execute one query. If there are no items - I don't think query to get items will be much slower than query to get their count (which is 0).

Comment: In most cases I agree. But those methods works differently so if you really care about performance you should use the best method for given situation there is no general solution. I saw queries where count was slower then tolist becuse of wrong indexes.